# How can i get the latest version of the Soap Api endpoint in Salesforce?

Tags: soap-api, wsdl

I am currently using version 48 for the Soap endpoint , how can i see what the lates version is so that I can update
The url is as follows:

```
https://xxxx/services/Soap/u/48.0
```

Also if there is a newer version , lets say 50, the url would be I assume

```
https://xxxx/services/Soap/u/50.0
```

Does that mean i need to download and update the WSDL in my project ,  if so where can i download this from , and would muy service reference need to be update ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is documented in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm

Comment: Documentation helped. thanks

Comment: Is there somewhere that outlines the changes / improvements between versions ?

Comment: Release Notes for every SF version are available at https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com - search for SOAP or WSDL. SOAP developer doc at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm has version-specific notes (if any) on an object-by-object basis